# Matching a domain with a URL

Tags: ruby

I need to check if a `URL` is match with a `domain` 
Ex:

http://www.opera.com/docs/changelogs/mac/
match with:
opera.com

http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/feature.html%3Fie%3DUTF8%26docId%3D1000423923
47
match with
amazon.co.uk

and to do so, I wrote this:

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI('http://cran.r-url.org/bin/max/')
domain = 'r-url.org'

urlToMatch = uri.host
check = urlToMatch.match(domain)


if check
  print "match \n"
else
  print "not a match \n"
end
```

Is there a better way of doing this?
Thank you

Comment: This looks fine to me.

Comment: `match` converts `domain` to a `Regexp` - you should [`escape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) it first since `.` has a special meaning.

Comment: Use the URI class, not Net::HTTP to load the functionality you need. Net::HTTP loads URI as part of what it needs but it's pulling in a lot of stuff you don't need if you're only comparing URLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require 'uri'

def url_on_domain?(url, domain)
  URI.parse(url).host.match(domain)
end

if url_on_domain?('http://cran.r-url.org/bin/max/', 'r-url.org')
  print "match \n"
else
  print "not a match \n"
end
```

Comment: This will also match any URL with 'r-url.org' such as 'other-r-url.org' which is probably not the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'uri'

domain = 'r-url.org'
check = URI.parse('http://cran.r-url.org/bin/max/').host == domain

if check
  print "match \n"
else
  print "not a match \n"
end
```

Comment: @Alex just leave a comment if the proposed answer doesn't work